# Automate Opening Multiple Calendars in Outlook

Tags: vba, outlook, exchange-server

I have a situation where an office just created a couple of dozen shared meeting room calendars for all of their office meeting rooms. There are about 100 or so employees. The plan right now is to send a document around to all of them explaining how to add all of these shared calendars to their outlooks. We are running a mixed environment with some outlook 2010 and some 2007 clients and the exchange server is 2010. IS there anyway to "push" all those calendars out automatically from exchange or is there a VB script that we could run on each computer to automate the process of all 100 people adding dozens of calendars?

Comment: This looks more like an Exchange admin issue than an actual programming question.

Comment: I have been looking at VB scripting in the hopes that this could automate the process.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is don't!

When you open your copy of Outlook, there is a pause while Outlook synchronises everything.  One of the things it has to synchronise is any calendars.  This can be a slooooow process particularly with busy calendars which I assume your meeting room calendars will be.

Comment: Fair point. However, right now we have three secretary that have all the calenders on thier outlooks and it isn't too bad. Will it get slower if more people are sharing them?

Comment: I do not know. At my last employer we booked rooms in this way. It was very convenient but we only opened a room's calendar when we needed to. I think the problem was we had 10 meeting rooms with 5 or 6 bookings a day for some months ahead because every team booked a room for its weekly or monthly meetings six months ahead so they were in everybody's calendar. Your system may be OK at the moment but as the bookings start building up, will it stay OK? A thought which has just occurred to me, I do not know if anyone was deleting the old bookings and what impact it was having if they did not.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced slowdowns when utilizing more than 12 calendars in shared mode if the access is higher than reviewer.  However, I have created my own workaround. Don't use direct booking.  Use an auto-attendant based access.

If you want many people to be able to alter the events, then you can do so by checking out the following:

Situation: When allowing multiple people to access and send the same event, you give them access to one another's account in most cases. This is unacceptable by security standards.

The fix:
Create an equipment calendar that can be used as a Department Calendar.  This is essentially the Exchange version of the corkboard calendar.  Everybody can add notes and send the updates through from this calendar.  How?  Follow this paradigm:  Everybody is a part of some grouping for security.  This security grouping in AD is Universal.  In Exchange you tie a Distribution list to the Security Group that's in AD.  Now you can email the group.  The group is the department.

The calendar you create as an equipment calendar will have some extra functions built in, right out of the box.  Using a shared calendar or folder in public listing, you'd have to script it all yourself.  Grant the group (not a single user) full access, and send as.

For the delegate, only the managers of the group or calendar (which could be a separate group that you set up to include a receptionist and the manager for scheduling purposes).  Allow the boss to auto-book, along with the receptionist.  The others do not.

Set the recurring policy and other policy settings.  Let nobody book out of policy.    This is not a room, it is a cork board.  When people don't follow the rules, they can lose access.  Grant access to the Distro group to the boss and receptionist.  Then, allow them to add anybody on premises that's in the department.  Now you have the calendar set up.

When they need to lock an appointment for editing, they go to the receptionist and have them book it, Sending it As their own personal ID, or go to the boss and have that person do it.  If it's a team shared meeting that will be noted and continually edited by all, you have anybody book it and send as the cork-board.

Since they all have full access to the cork-board, they can edit the calendar, and since they have send as, they can send the updates to everybody.  Now you just add the group as a recipient and they all get an invite.  Set them up with sync, and they'll always be able to respond.

Have the responses marked read then autoredirect to the receptionist who can remove those who are busy from the attendees.  Now you know who's at the meeting.  Anybody can add themselves by clicking Copy to My Calendar, and they'll show up as an attendee, forwarding their response to the receptionist, who can make any other arrangements necessary.  And so on.

If you make sure that the Calendar attaches the name of the booking ID to those events that are booked from outside it (receptionist and boss), they'll know which events they shouldn't delete.  Want to forgo that ability?  Script a change in their access to the calendar, set the Calendar itself to be able to EDIT OWN, DELETE OWN.  Set all but manager and reception to Edit OWN, Delete OWN.  Set Manager and reception to Owner access.

Now they can all still edit and send using the calendar, but only the manager and Receptionist can actually lock events.